# Map doesn't get drawn on user location when screen loads

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm still very new to Flutter/Dart and I'm using the flutter_bloc bloc/repository pattern and I'm getting a strange behaviour in my app.
All prints show that all streams and bloc pattern are working correctly, incoming states are carrying the coordinates and the variable that hold the newest coordinates is never null, but when MapScreen loads, it doesn't draw the map on userLocation coordinates.
Also, when pressing center button sometimes I get `The method 'move' was called on null.` error.

In MapScreen `userLocation` that gets its value from incoming state

```
return BlocBuilder<MapBloc, MapState>(
//        bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
        builder: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
      userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
//      if (state is LocationStream) {
//        userLocation = (state).location;
//      }
      return Scaffold(
```

is then used to draw the map at user location

```
child: FlutterMap(
                    options: MapOptions(
                      center: userLocation,
                      minZoom: 5.0,
                      maxZoom: 19.0,
                    ),
                    mapController: _mapController,
```

to display user on the map

```
Marker(
       point: userLocation,
       height: 200,
       width: 200,
       builder: (context) => IconButton(
           icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
           color: Colors.red,
           iconSize: 60,
           onPressed: () {
            print('icon tapped');
           },
       ),
     ),
```

and to re center the map on user location .

```
RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print(
                            ' @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   userLocation is $userLocation');
                        _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'center',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

The strange behaviour is that sometimes when I press center button I get `The method 'move' was called on null.` error, but not always.

Sometimes works every time I press it, but sometimes it finds the value null after a few times that worked.

At first build, center button works as expected and centers the map, but always finds the value null after a Hot-reload or Hot-restart..

Can you see what I'm doing wrong ?
Thank you very much for your time and help.

Complete UI code:

```
class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final MapRepository _mapRepository;
  final MapController _mapController;
//  final AlertRepository _alertRepository;
  List<Marker> alerts;
  LatLng userLocation;
  MapScreen(
      {Key key, @required this.name, @required MapRepository mapRepository})
      : assert(mapRepository != null),
        _mapRepository = mapRepository,
        _mapController = MapController(),
//        _alertRepository = alertRepository,
        super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MapBloc, MapState>(
//        bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
        builder: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
      userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
//      if (state is LocationStream) {
//        userLocation = (state).location;
//      }
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent, fontSize: 40),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.exit_to_app,
                color: Colors.orange,
                size: 35,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(
                  LoggedOut(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 570,
                  width: 320,
                  child: FlutterMap(
                    options: MapOptions(
                      center: userLocation,
                      minZoom: 5.0,
                      maxZoom: 19.0,
                    ),
                    mapController: _mapController,
                    layers: [
                      //
//        PolygonLayer(polygonOpts, map, stream)
//                    PolygonLayerOptions(
//                      polygons:
//                    ),
                      TileLayerOptions(
                          urlTemplate:
                              'https://api.openrouteservice.org/mapsurfer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf62484c4b65d85bc844eca3a2c6b9f300ddf4',
//                              urlTemplate:
//                                  'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                          keepBuffer: 20),
                      new MarkerLayerOptions(
                        markers: [
                          Marker(
                            point: userLocation,
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                            builder: (context) => IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                              color: Colors.red,
                              iconSize: 60,
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('icon tapped');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
//                          Marker(
//                            height: ,
//                            builder: BlocBuilder<AlertBloc,AlertState>(
//                                builder: (BuildContext context, AlertState state) {
//                                  alerts = (state as AlertsUpdated).alerts;
//                                  return
//                                }),
//                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print(
                            ' @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   userLocation is $userLocation');
                        _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'center',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //TODO  this goes actually in a alert icon callbac, here just navigates icons vc
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'alert',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I also put together a sample app in case you want to have a look at it.
https://github.com/vinnytwice/flutter_app

UPDATE:

After discovering that that FlutterMapmust be in a stateful widget I changed mine. On incoming state I performed a check on the State type and in side that called setState() with the new value from state. Error.. A builder that rebuilds building widget kind of error if I recall the error correctly. .. BlocBuilder wasn't the right choice anymore so I swapped it for a BlocListener instead that has a callback on States, and called setState() in there.
FlutterMap gets now drawn on userLocation on buttonPressed even after Hot-reload or Hot-restart..and no more `The method 'move' was called on null.` errors.. so that one is solved.

Still FlutterMap doesn't get drawn on userLocation at screen load.
Can you see what I'm missing? Some initial coordinates perhaps?
Anyways.. shouldn't setState() keep track of where userLocation is used and rebuild those widgets ?

If I call _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);right after setState() than the map will follow the user location, useful in a step-by-step navigator, but is not what I need..also if you pan it as soon as a new state comes in, the map moves..

So the new code is:

```
// stateful widget using BlocListener:

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final MapRepository _mapRepository;
//  MapController _mapController;
//  final AlertRepository _alertRepository;

  MapScreen(
      {Key key, @required this.name, @required MapRepository mapRepository})
      : assert(mapRepository != null),
        _mapRepository = mapRepository,
//        _mapController = MapController(),
//        _alertRepository = alertRepository,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  List<Marker> alerts;

  LatLng userLocation;

  MapController _mapController = MapController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<MapBloc, MapState>(
//        bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
      listener: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
//      userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
        if (state is LocationStream) {
          setState(() {
            userLocation = (state).location;
          });
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent, fontSize: 40),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.exit_to_app,
                color: Colors.orange,
                size: 35,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
//              BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(
//                LoggedOut(),
//              );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 570,
                  width: 320,
                  child: FlutterMap(
                    options: MapOptions(
                      center: userLocation,
                      minZoom: 5.0,
                      maxZoom: 19.0,
                    ),
                    mapController: _mapController,
                    layers: [
                      //
//        PolygonLayer(polygonOpts, map, stream)
//                    PolygonLayerOptions(
//                      polygons:
//                    ),
                      TileLayerOptions(
                          urlTemplate:
                              'https://api.openrouteservice.org/mapsurfer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf62484c4b65d85bc844eca3a2c6b9f300ddf4',
//                              urlTemplate:
//                                  'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                          keepBuffer: 20),
                      new MarkerLayerOptions(
                        markers: [
                          Marker(
                            point: userLocation,
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                            builder: (context) => IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                              color: Colors.red,
                              iconSize: 60,
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('icon tapped');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
//                          Marker(
//                            height: ,
//                            builder: BlocBuilder<AlertBloc,AlertState>(
//                                builder: (BuildContext context, AlertState state) {
//                                  alerts = (state as AlertsUpdated).alerts;
//                                  return
//                                }),
//                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print(
                            ' @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   userLocation is $userLocation');
                        _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'center',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //TODO  this goes actually in a alert icon callbac, here just navigates icons vc
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'alert',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the question guidelines to improve the changes you will get responses: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JoãoSoares you're absolutely right, I actually thought I did put a sample code in the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please don't add things like 'Solved' or 'see update' into the question title - it isn't needed on this site. Also, it looks like your update is the answer, so write it as an answer, post it, then mark it as the answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry for the title thing. I actually din't post it as an answer because not everything is fixed. Map still doesn't get drawn on `userLocation` when  MapScreen loads.
Also I didn't edit the question and delete the old part I found the solution for, but put it under UPDATE to be useful to others showing the whole  problem history..

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work.  I ended up using an approach that, thinking that with just a `Stream<LatLng> userLocation` I'd be sorted, I put aside a week ago because I didn't know yet how to use Futures properly.

In repository I use a method that just returns a `Future<LatLng>`:

```
Future<LatLng> getLocation() async {
    print('getLocation() called');
    Position position;
    LatLng location;
    try {
      position = await locationManager
          .getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
      location = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      print('getLocation() location is: $location');
      return location;
    } catch (error) {
      print(
          'getLocation(): error getting current location: ${error.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

From `BlocProvider` in `main()` I now send two events:

```
BlocProvider<MapBloc>(create: (context) {
          return MapBloc(
            mapRepository: mapRepository,
          )
            ..add(GetLocationStream())
            ..add(GetInitialLocation());
        }),
```

In bloc yield a state with the value from `getLocation().

```
Stream<MapState> _mapCenterMapToState(GetInitialLocation event) async* {
    location = await _mapRepository.getLocation();
    print('_mapCenterMapToState location is : ${_mapRepository.getLocation()}');
    yield MapLoading(location);
  }
```

In `BlocListener` I added a new state check and used the state value to move the map.

```
BlocListener<MapBloc, MapState>(
            listener: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
          if (state is LocationStream) {
            setState(() {
              userLocation = (state).location;
            });
          }
          if (state is MapLoading) {
            userLocation = (state).location;
            print(
                ' @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ MapBloc initial state location is : $userLocation');
            _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
          }
        })
```

Map now loads at user location but doesn't move with it, user location icon is constantly updated, and center button centers the map on user location when pressed.

Hope this long question and answer will help others just starting out as I am.
Cheers.